# Finding routes instead of straight line in Network Analyst O/D cost matrix?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, origin-destination

I have 53 locations of origin-destination lat and long and a shapefile of the road network of the study region. I would like to find the shapefile of all O/D routes. I tried with network analyst, O/D cost matrix. But there I got an only straight line from one point to another. But instead of a straight line, I need routes as like it shows on “new route” in network analyst.

Is this possible in ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

The O/D cost matrix creation result is only a table or straight line. Table values in that matrix based on true forms of routes.

If you want to get only geometry, you should use ModelBuilder with “new route” tool.